# Facebook Graph API: Not able to enable Explicitly Shared. What to do?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have some problems using the Facebook Open Graph API!

I just addet a new Facebook App for publishing some bike and run courses via a iOS and Android app - I just did that the same way as in an another app, which is doing kindly the same!
Anyway - I can't find the open graph-settings in the facebook-developer-dashboard for the new app!

See screenshot -> left: old app, right: new app
[image: left: old app, right: new app]
As you can see - there is no possibilty to change open-graph settings!

The Facebook Api (v2.8) responses, that I have to enable the "explicitly shared", but I can't!

```
{
  "error": {
"message": "(#100) You haven't enabled Explicitly Shared for this action type (***************) yet. Please update your Open Graph settings in the App Dashboard",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 100,
"fbtrace_id": "EEaAYiLwyas"
  }
}
```

I do everything exactly the same way as in the old app, which works great.

Do anyone have any ideas what to do?

Comment: Custom OG stories are deprecated, you can not use them any more in new apps. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_8_deprecations

Comment: do you know if old apps using custom OG stories will be deprecated too in the future?

Comment: That is explained in the Deprecation Guide linked to from the above document …